# Azure DevOps Server - multistage YAML pipeline - release couldn't start

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

On my Azure DevOps Server instance (2020 Update 1.1) I have easy multistage YAML pipeline with Build job (run against BuildPool) and release job (run against ReleasePool). Build job is executed successfully. In release pool there are many idle agents but job is in waiting state with message:

> The agent request is not running because all potential agents are running other requests. Current position in queue: 1
> No agents in pool ReleasePool are currently able to service this request.

Other pipelines on the server against ReleasePool are executed.
This pipeline was executed one month past also successfully, and since this execution the YAML definition stays unchanged.
Pipeline have no explicit demands, I'm trying to identify implicit demands (from used tasks - I have checked tasks.json task manifests for each used task) - but there isn't used no task with demands.
I have no idea what I could try next.

Is the way how to diagnostic how are agents assigned to the pipeline jobs? I have admin permissions and access to the DB, I'm ready to do very deep analysis.

Comment: Since you have confirmed there is no related demands setting and definition unchanged, a good starting point is to check the "Release pool" in TFS agent pools if there is any job queued inside.

Answer (score 0):

Since other tasks are running fine, maybe a specific demands on selected agents are not met and this is preventing an agent to be found.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops-2020&tabs=yaml

Or else, it's a bug.
I found a similar issue here, and Microsoft responded July 2022 with:
"We have released a fix for this issue"

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/no-agent-found-in-pool-azure-pipelines/870000

It is however not clear to me if this only applied to Azure DevOps or also to Azure DevOps Server.
But since your on 2020 Update 1.1, updating couldn't harm you:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2020u1?view=azure-devops-2020